# How to change a color of a link in CSS class

Tags: css

I need to change a color of a title of a blog entry in a teaser (Drupal views). Here is my CSS:

```
.blog-title h2 a,a:visited,a:link,a:active {
  color: #505556;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: bolder
 }
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: So? Where can we help you? The CSS class looks good so far ...

Comment: show your html please what you exactly want ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to help without seeing your HTML code. As a assumption try like this way.

```
.blog-title h2 a,
.blog-title h2 a:visited,
.blog-title h2 a:link,
.blog-title h2 a:active {
 color: #505556 !important;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by:

```
.blog-title a,a:visited,a:link,a:active {
  color: #405c77;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder
 }
```